# Eigenvalues of the total angular momentum operator in $d>3$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory

How to calculate them?

What are their degeneracy?

Comment: It is not clear what the total angular momentum operator *is* in higher dimensions, since angular momentum is, classically, a two-form, which is a vector with a natural total "norm" only in three-dimensions (and in two, where it's just a number).

Answer (score 4):

For $d=3$ the group theoretic meaning of total angular momentum is that it is the Casimir operator of $SO(3)$. For $SO(d)$ where $d>3$ you have more than one Casimir operator, so it's not clear what you mean by "total angular momentum"
In particular the number of Casimir operators is $[d]/2$, where $[d]=d$ or $d-1$ depending whether $d$ is even or odd.

Comment: i actually mean the laplace operator on the sphere.